# Comparing date/timestamps in JS

Tags: javascript, date, time

For a website, we're scheduling promotions through metafields: start datetime, end datetime (format "2022-12-02T13:00:00+00:00"). In JS, i'm pulling those values and comparing them to the JS current time by converting to Epoch.

Is the way i'm approaching this fool-proof?

```
let currentEpoch = new Date(Date.now()).getTime()
let startPromotionEpoch = new Date(response.data.shop.promotion_start.value).getTime()
let endPromotionEpoch = new Date(response.data.shop.promotion_end.value).getTime()

if(currentEpoch > startPromotionEpoch && currentEpoch < endPromotionEpoch) {
    // website updates
}
```

As far as i'm seeing, after extensive testing, this seems to work.

One issue i'm having though, is that it's currently Wintertime. This means that i have to enter my desired datetime in the metafield minus 1 hour for it to match my code. Ideally, this is covered by the code. How would i approach this?

Comment: _"This means that i have to enter my desired datetime in the metafield minus 1 hour for it to match my code."_ - what _exactly_ are you entering? The value `2022-12-02T13:00:00+00:00` directly, in string form? The `+00:00` part at the end should be different here, and _not_ the actual time.

Comment: I'm selecting it through a datetime picker which shows like "02/12/2022, 13:00" in that field. Pulling its value with graphQL results in 2022-12-02T13:00:00+00:00.

Comment: Oh so you mean +00:00 is to target DST scenarios? Okay but since i'm pulling in 2022-12-02T13:00:00+00:00 through GraphQL, how would i compensate for that in the code?

Comment: The value you get from GraphQL should contain `+01:00` already, if that is not the case, then I would assume storing the value _into_ it was not handled correctly somehow.

Comment: Apparently there seems to be a bug in Shopify where the DST values are not correctly set.